# C# get textBox value from another Form

Tags: c#

I have Login form where `textBox1` contain user ID.I'm trying to use entered ID in another windows form.In LOGIN Form `strvalue` have ID, but in Another Form `strvalue` is empty.  Sorry for dumb question.

code - LOGIN Form:

```
public static string strvalue = "";

private void button22_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)       
{       
    strvalue = textBox1.Text;   
}
```

code Another Form:

```
LOGIN LF = new LOGIN();

MessageBox.Show(LF.strvalue);
```

Comment: you never showed (display) the other form to the user. I would totally expect the value to be empty

Comment: OP you should go read more about OOP and events. once you got a deeper understanding you will figure this out easily.

Comment: [Duplicate 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062575/) [duplicate 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800731/) [duplicate 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032484/) [duplicate 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836398/) [duplicate 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316230/) [duplicate 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092707/) ...

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling events and flow control appropriately. Like steve said, it is necessary for you to display your login form in response to a particular event or function call. Afterwards, you can access public methods of the current running instance for LOGIN Form.

You can also take a look at this [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/communicate-between-two-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks guys, I did it.