# Accessing textbox variables from another class

Tags: c#, .net, class

I have a windows form (c#). In the form, the user inputs some text and it then gets saved to an XML. Each time the solution starts, it reads the XML.

At first, I was just testing so I had a master class. Then I started creating different classes and run into a problem.
I can't access the values from the textboxes of the form from the other classes. There are a few other posts asking the same, but I couldn't manage to solve it.

This is what I have:

```
namespace Emailing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {

        InitializeComponent();
        XmlController xc = new XmlController();
        xc.readXml(); //reads the xml when starts
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        XmlController xc2 = new XmlController();
        xc2.updateXml(); //updates the xmls when the users clicks a button
        }
    }
}


namespace Emailing
{
class XmlController
{   
    public void updateXml()
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.TableName = "Server";
        dt.Columns.Add("Server");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        DataRow row = ds.Tables["Server"].NewRow();
        row["Server"] = Form1.textBox6.Text;          
        ds.Tables["Server"].Rows.Add(row);
        ds.WriteXml("Emailer.xml");
    }

    public void readXml()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml("Emailer.xml");
        Form1.textBox6.Text = ds.Tables["Server"].Rows[0][0].ToString();

    }

}
```

}

I tried several things with no success.
From what I read, the "best" practice would be to create an interface. I tried but couldn't make it work.
I also tried creating a get set method for the textBox but couldn't make it work. I'm not sure where it should go.

Thanks for your time,

Comment: [Duplicate 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062575/), [duplicate 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800731/), [duplicate 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032484/), [duplicate 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836398/), [duplicate 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316230/), [duplicate 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092707/) ...

Comment: @DourHighArch Made my Day with the dup list :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access something from "outside" of a class (the form is a class),
you need it to be Public.

Edit:

```
namespace Emailing
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      ...
    }

    public string TextOfTextBox1 { get { return Textbox1.Text; } }
  }
}
```

If you have, lets say a 'LoginForm',
You might want to add a property to fetch the given Username as `public string UserName { get { return userNameTextBox.Text; } }`
(same for the Password, Remmember me, Etc...)

Comment: Where should I add the property? In the class? In a method (public Form1()?

Comment: edited answer with example...
general answer, in your Form's partial class

Answer (score 1):

You have instantiated the XmlController class 2 times.

this means that you have 2 objects of the same class, but it are different objects.

what you should do is instantiate the class once and use this object also for the button_Click event (see code)

```
namespace Emailing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    private XmlController xc;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        xc = new XmlController();
        xc.readXml(); //reads the xml when starts
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        xc.updateXml(); //updates the xmls when the users clicks a button
    }
}
```

}

however I do suggest you start experimenting with the MVVM pattern see: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial

Comment: Thanks!. Ill try the MVVM pattern.

Comment: just read yourself into it a little bit, at a certain moment it will come in Handy :)