# C# Passing data Between windows(WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

Recently picked up C# in university, trying to work out how to pass the variable "name" in MainWindow.xaml to ThirdWindow.xaml?

**The below code is for the main window where the data is assigned to the variable "name"**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();    
    }

    public void NameBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string name = NameBox.Text;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SecondWindow newWin = new SecondWindow();
        newWin.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

**The below code is for the third window**

```
public partial class ThirdWindow : Window
{
    public ThirdWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();      
    }

    public void LstThanks_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LstThanks.Items.Add(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: When/ How is `ThirdWindow` opened? I only see `SecondWindow`. Should it be opened in the `NameBox_TextChanged` method?

Comment: [Duplicate 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062575/), [duplicate 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800731/), [duplicate 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032484/), [duplicate 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836398/), [duplicate 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316230/), [duplicate 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092707/) ...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass that string name variable in the constructor as an argument to the *ThirdWindow* on **Button_Click** event.

```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var name = "your name";
        var newWin = new ThirdWindow(name);
        newWin.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
```

That string text will be available in the constructor of *ThirdWindow*.

```
public partial class ThirdWindow: Window
{
    public ThirdWindow(string name)
    {
        InitializeComponent();      
    }

    public void LstThanks_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LstThanks.Items.Add(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable through the constructor of the new window

```
var win = new ThirdWindow(name);

public ThirdWindow(string name)
{
    InitializeComponent();      
}
```

Another method is to pass it through an event message.  This will require you to write a new message and add an event listener to your constructor in the ThirdWindow class.  If you google this there are a variety of examples out there on how to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are defining a **local variable** name. This variable is visible only inside the {} block. So we cannot use it anywhere else.

```
public void NameBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string name = NameBox.Text;
}
```

You could add a new string property into second window and pass value through that to all the way into third form.

So, add new property into your two windows (SecondWindow, ThirdWindow)

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

These properties are holding the data for whole their lifetime (until they are closed).

Remove NameBox_TextChanged event handling, because we don't need it.
Add property setting inside your buttons click event

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SecondWindow newWin = new SecondWindow();
    newWin.Name = NameBox.Text; //Store value into SecondWindow variable
    newWin.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

Now when SecondWindow is visible (Show is called), you have name value available in Name variable and you should be able to copy this behavior for ThirdWindow.

Answer (score 0):

If the `ThirdWindow` window is dependent on the `name` value then you can pass it through the constructor:

```
public partial class ThirdWindow : Window
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ThirdWindow(string name)
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

or if not then make a method on the `ThridWindow` to set the `name`:

```
public partial class ThirdWindow : Window
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void SetName(string name)
    {  
        Name = name;
    }
}
```